# ¿Cómo generar direcciones IP aleatorias en C++?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo el siguiente código, me salta un error diciendo que el la línea donde dice `m[i]=0.0.0.0 + rand() % (255.255.255.255);` me dice que hay demasiados puntos decimales ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ya puse el arreglo como si fuera de tipo `double` pero no me deja.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    double  m[100];
 
    srand(time(NULL));
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        m[i]= 0.0.0.0 + rand() % (255.255.255.255);
        cout<<m[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Pude hacer 4 arreglos y que cada uno de ellos vaya desde 0 hasta 255 ,¿mi pregunta es ahora ¿como puedo concatenar todos ellos separados por punto decimal  en un arreglo de números flotantes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {     
    double  m[10];
    float  n1[10];
    float  n2[10];
    float  n3[10];
    float  n4[10]; 
 
    srand(time(NULL));
  
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){      
        n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
        n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
        n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
        n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255);       
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){      
        m[i] = n1[i] + "." + n2[i] + "." + n3[i] + "." + n4[i];     
    }
             
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx no es un numero.. por mas que se llame numero IP, no es un numero. un numero tiene una parte entera y una decimal... y si quisieras usar separadores de miles, tampoco es un numero, porque para cualquier computadora, eso es solo la vista.. el numero no tiene separadores de miles.. ahora que sabes esto... cual es la pregunta????

Comment: Claro, tendrías que generar cada sector de la ip por separado para que tenga sentido.

Comment: @gbianchi mi pregunta es ¿como puedo generar 10 números aleatorios entre 0.0.0.0 asta 255.255.255.255?gracias

Comment: @N.N. ¿eso no me consumiría muchos recursos ?

Comment: para nada.. estas generando 40 numeros aleatorios y armando las IP.. donde esta la gran consumision de recursos?

Comment: En vez de generar un "número" con tres puntos decimales, generás cuatro entre 0 y 255 y después los almacenás en un string separados por un punto, y los guardás en  `m[i]`.

Comment: @gbianchi me refiero a que futuramente voy a crear muchas mas ip

Comment: que son muchos mas? de cuantos hablamos? millones? trillones? porque para el caso, es lo mismo.. si ibas a generar numero asi de grandes, ibas a ocupar montones de espacio igual... no se que vas a hacer, pero tal vez deberias revisar lo que realmente querias hacer...

Comment: @N.N. actualice el código,¿se puede hacer con numeros flotantes ?

Comment: @gbianchi hablo de todas las ipv4 del mundo ,actualice el código

Comment: No se entiende para qué querés usar números flotantes. Si lo que querés es que toda la ip sea un sólo número podrías usar un integer y después buscar alguna manera de separar cada uno de los 4bytes que representarían cada sector de la ip.

Comment: Tu quieres generar todas las combinaciones de ipv4?

Comment: @Japv si quiero hacer eso

Comment: aja.. y para que tenes que hacerlo con numeros aleatorios? y donde las vas a guardar? son 4.3 billones de conbinaciones. Tu pregunta, ahora, se torno totalmente ilogica. y si.. va a ocupar un monton de memoria, pero en todos los formatos lo va a hacer...

Comment: "como puedo concatenar todos ellos.separados por punto decimal en un arreglo de números flotantes " no, no podes.. no entendiste nada de la explicacion que te dimos???

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo, ya te he escrito varias veces y no dices nada, cuando uno recibe ayuda de la comunidad debe ser agradecido, estas creando un mal precedente, en ninguna de las preguntas que has hecho has dado voto en ninguna respuesta, ni aceptado ninguna, por favor si las respuestas te fueron útiles dales un voto y a la que haya resuelto tu problema marcala como aceptada

Answer (score 7):

Una dirección IP no son 4 números separados por puntos. Esa es solo una forma de representar la dirección IP para que sea más legible para el ser humano.

Una dirección IP es una secuencia de 32 bits. Por ejemplo:

```
01000111000111010011101010111001
```

Pero claro, este número así puesto es un poco complicado de memorizar. Así que lo que se hace es que se divide en 4 grupos de 8 dígitos

```
01000111 00011101 00111010 10111001
```

Y después se calcula el número decimal que le corresponde a ese grupo:

```
01000111 00011101 00111010 10111001
   71   .   29   .   58   .  185
```

Así que para calcular una dirección IP aleatoria no necesitas calcular 4 números aleatorios en el rango 1-255. Basta con que calcules un número de 32 bits:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());    

int ip = distrib(gen);

Para obtener la ip en grupos de 4 números basta con separar grupos de 8 bits:

for( int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    std::cout << (ip & 0xFF);
    if ( i<3) std::cout << '.';
    ip >>= 8;
}
```

> como puedo concatenar todos ellos.separados por punto decimal en un arreglo de números flotantes ?

No puedes y no debes.

**No puedes**

Los números en coma flotante **no tienen** puntos o comas, esos caracteres se añaden al número decimal que se imprime para que sea comprensible por un ser humano. Los números en coma flotante son secuencias binarias cuyos bits se interpretan de forma diferente a cómo se interpreta un número entero.

De hecho, ambos tipos ocupan 32 bits, es decir, la secuencia

```
01000111000111010011101010111001
```

si la tratamos como un `float` representará el número `40250.7`. Sin embargo, si la interpretamos como un entero, nos encontraremos con el número `1193097913`.

Como ves, en la memoria no se almacenan ni puntos ni comas, esas divisiones solo existen de cara al usuario.

**No debes**

Los números en coma flotante nos permiten almacenar números muy grandes (o muy pequeños) en unos pocos bytes. Esta gran capacidad tiene un precio y es que su precisión es relativa.

A modo de ejemplo, en un número de tipo `float` solo puedes fiarte de sus 6 primeros dígitos, mientras que en el caso de un `double`, la precisión alcanza los 12 dígitos.

El resto de los dígitos son considerados basura o poco fiables. Esto se debe a que en binario hay decimales que no pueden expresarse con un número finito de bits y eso da lugar a imprecisiones.

Answer (score 2):

Para generar todas las combinaciones que existen de **direcciones ipv4**, debemos tener en cuenta que una **dirección ipv4** está compuesta de cuatro números que van desde **0 a 255** cada uno, donde la primera dirección ip es **0.0.0.0** y la última es **255.255.255.255**, el número total de combinaciones es **255 * 255 * 255 * 255** o **255^4**, es decir el total de combinaciones de **direcciones ipv4** es **‭4.294.967.296‬ o 2^32 combinaciones**. Como ves este número es bastante grande, por lo que obtener todas estas **ip** va a requerir aplicar el enfoque conocido como **fuerza bruta**, el cual demandará tiempo y recurso de tu PC.

Aclarado esto acá te dejo el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const unsigned long ipv4 = 4294967295;
    char *DireccionesIp[ipv4];
    unsigned long index = 0;
    char sbyte1[20] = "";
    char sbyte2[20] = "";
    char sbyte3[20] = "";
    char sbyte4[20] = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) 
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < 255; k++) 
        {
          for (int l = 0; l < 255; l++) 
          {
            sprintf(sbyte1,"%d", i);
            sprintf(sbyte2,"%d", j);
            sprintf(sbyte3,"%d", k);
            sprintf(sbyte4,"%d", l);
            
            strcat(sbyte1, ".");
            strcat(sbyte1, sbyte2);
            strcat(sbyte1, ".");
            strcat(sbyte1, sbyte3);
            strcat(sbyte1, ".");
            strcat(sbyte1, sbyte4);
            
            DireccionesIp[index] = sbyte1;
            cout<<DireccionesIp[index]<<"\n";
            index++;
          }
        }
      }
    }                         

    return 0;
}
```

En este código se crea un arreglo con una longitud que permita almacenar todo el rango de **direcciones ipv4**, para ello se usará el tipo de dato **unsigned long** y se declararan cuatro arreglos de caracteres:

**sbyte1:** guardara el primer número de la dirección ip **(0 - 255)**.

**sbyte2:** guardará el segundo número de la dirección ip **(0 - 255)**.

**sbyte3:** guardará el tercer número de la dirección ip **(0 - 255)**.

**sbyte4:** guardará el cuarto número de la dirección ip **(0 - 255)**.

Todas estas cadenas concatenadas entre ellas y por el caracter **"."**, conformarán cada una de las **direcciones ipv4**.

Para generar todas las combinaciones creamos **4 ciclos for anidados**, donde cada uno empezará en **0** y terminará en **255**.

Dentro del último **ciclo for** convertimos a cadena de caracteres cada iterador (**i**, **j**, **k**, **l**) usando la **función** **sprintf**.

Una vez que todos esos números (**i**, **j**, **k**, **l**) se hallan convertido a cadena de caracteres entonces iremos concatenando cada número con el caracter **"."** y el próximo número. Para esta concatenación usamos la **función** **strcat**. Una vez hecho todo este proceso de **concatenación** es que obtenemos una ip válida que será guardada en el **arreglo DireccionesIp** y mostrada en pantalla.

**Nota:** Generar todas las ip llevará tiempo, por lo que en vez de iterar hasta **255**, bien podrías iterar hasta un número menor, al menos para comprobar que el algoritmo hace lo que deseas.

Comment: gracias por sus  respuestas  hay alguna forma de recompensar en stackoverflow

Comment: @eferion gracias a ti por tu respuesta hay halguna forma de recompensar

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo, si, puedes darle un voto a cada respuesta y marcar como aceptada la q mas te haya gustado y resuelto el problema

Comment: gracias ,lo hare, ¿para hacer menos ip quito en todos los ciclos 2555 y pongo un numero menor ?

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo, si, prueba con numeros pequennos(10,20) y ve subiendo poco a poco

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo, si las respuestas te fueron utiles dales un voto y a la que resolvio tu problema marcala como aceptada, gracias